# Why am I not getting any data back from website?

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

So I'm brand new the whole web scraping thing. I've been working on a project that requires me to get the word of the day from [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/word-of-the-day). I have successfully grabbed the word now I just need to get the definition, but when I do so I get this result:

> Avuncular (Correct word of the day)
>
> Definition:
>
> []

here's my code:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://www.merriam-webster.com/word-of-the-day')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

word = tree.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/main/article/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/h1/text()')

WOTD = str(word)
WOTD = WOTD[2:]
WOTD = WOTD[:-2]

print(WOTD.capitalize())


print("Definition:")

wordDef = tree.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/p[1]/text()')

print(wordDef)
```

[] is supposed to be the first definition but won't work for some reason.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xpath is slightly off. Here's the correct one:

```
wordDef = tree.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/main/article/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/p[1]/text()')
```

Note div[3] after main/article instead of div[2]. Now when running you should get:

```
Avuncular
Definition:
[' suggestive of an uncle especially in kindliness or geniality']
```

Comment: Thanks! I copied the XPath using chrome. I must have copied the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to avoid hardcoding index within xpath, the following would be an alternative to your current attempt:

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

page = requests.get('https://www.merriam-webster.com/word-of-the-day')
tree = fromstring(page.text)
word = tree.xpath("//*[@class='word-header']//h1")[0].text
wordDef = tree.xpath("//h2[contains(.,'Definition')]/following-sibling::p/strong")[0].tail.strip()
print(f'{word}\n{wordDef}')
```

If the `wordDef` fails to get the full portion then try replacing with the below one:

```
wordDef = tree.xpath("//h2[contains(.,'Definition')]/following-sibling::p")[0].text_content()
```

Output:

```
avuncular
suggestive of an uncle especially in kindliness or geniality
```